# GPS remains on after app with Service using LocationListener exits

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I've got a problem with my app on Nexus 5 phones. It seems to work on other phones as S4 with Android 4.4.2. The problem: GPS is still on after the service app is closed by the user and it's not possible to do anything to turn it off, only reboot works. The problem happens after a while and I suspect the problem happens if the service is killed by OS, the location listner seems not to be "cleared" by OS.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
........
thread = new HandlerThread("thread",
        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND);
........
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
...........
if (!thread.isAlive())
    thread.start();

// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.removeUpdates(this);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 5, this,
            thread.getLooper());
return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    .........
thread.quit();
lm.removeUpdates(this);
    .........
}
```

Comment: Try using the Service's thread (instead of the inner HandlerThread) to listen for updates `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 5, this);` - (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613888/locationclient-doesnt-give-callback-when-screen-light-goes-off-but-my-wakefulth/17861235#17861235)

Comment: @Sean Barbeau Ok, I'll try, but I don't understand why it could be the problem, is it a known bug?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  In your current design, you might also want to put `lm.removeUpdates(this)` prior to `thread.quit()`, to give the framework a reference to a live thread when processing the removal of the listener.  And, use `thread.quitSafely()`.  Maybe there is an internal bug related to finished threads.  Seems though, from the LocationManager docs, that in general your use of the HandlerThread is permitted.

Comment: If I well remember at the beginning the calls was in reverse order, but it worked on the emulator, but it crashed with my phone :) But I can try again.

Comment: @SeanBarbeau I tried but it doesn't work. I suggested my customer to change the phone because I think it must be an hw problem of nexus 5.

Comment: Bummer.  Could be Nexus 5 issue, but most likely sw.  The other place to check is to make sure your activity is tearing down the Service correctly.  Some devices are more aggressive about killing Services that aren't explicitly ended than others.